# Can't connect via HDMI cable after setting the touchscreen

Tags: raspbian, boot, hdmi, pi-2, touchscreen

i have been working a lot with HDMI cable and raspberry pi 2 and i was able to log into raspbian using a screen with HDMI
recently i have used a touchscreen for the raspberry pi :
It's a  **3.5" adafruit touchscreen**, so I followed this tutorial
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/easy-install

i was able to work with the touchscreen but it's a little bit irresponsive ans frreezes sometime so i switched back to HDMI

but from the terminal when loading raspbian using a HDMI cable , the terminal stops in the first steps after about 3 secondes of booting

this is a capture from what i got and what i have supposed that is the source of the problem

```
stmpe-spi spi0.1 : unknow chip id:0x0
stmpe-spi: probe of spi0.1 : failed with error -22
fb_hx8357d :module is from the staging directory ,the quality is unknown ,uou have been warned .
```

and the latest line shows :

```
random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

please help thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it by uncommenting the line

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

an uncommenting the adafruit part in the file

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

But i still want to get an answer without forcing the HDMI !!!